# Ricci form is closed?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,g,J)$ be an **almost Kähler manifold** and let $\rho$ denote its *Ricci form*
$$
\rho(X,Y) = \operatorname{ric}^{\mbox{c}}(JX,Y)
$$
where $\operatorname{ric}^{\mbox{c}}$ is the $J$-invariant part of the Ricci tensor of the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.

If $\rho(X,JY)=\operatorname{ric}(X,Y)$ (i.e. $(M,g,J)$ has *$J$-invariant Ricci tensor*), is it true that $\rho$ is a closed $2$-form?

A second question is:

what are well known results from the theory of Kähler manifolds valid in almost Kahler manifolds with $J$-invariant Ricci tensor?

Answer (score 3):

For a **Kähler** manifold $(M^{2n}, g, J)$, the Ricci 2-form $\rho(X, Y):={\rm Ric}(JX, Y)$ is closed, of type $(1, 1)$, and represents (up to a scaling factor $\frac{1}{2\pi}$) the de Rham cohomology of the first Chern class of $(M, J)$.

For generic **almost-Kähler manifolds** (i.e. the almost complex structure $J$ is not integrable), none of these properties remains true for the tensor $\rho(X, Y)={\rm Ric}'(JX, Y)$, where ${\rm Ric}'$ denotes the $J$-invariant part of the Ricci tensor.

For details on almost Kähler manifolds with $J$-invariant Ricci tensor, see the paper of T. Draghici, *Almost Kähler 4-manifolds with $J$-invariant Ricci tensor*, Houston J. Math. 25
(1999), 133–145, or  papers of V. Apostolov, or K. Sekigawa.

Comment: Dear @314159. Thank you very much for your answer and the references. 

Could you please give us an elementary example or short analysis to justify your affirmation about $\rho(X, Y)={\rm Ric}'(JX, Y)$ for generic **almost-Kähler manifolds**.

Comment: For an almost-Kähler manifold $(M, g, J)$ the vanishing of the Nijenhueis tensor $N$ is equivalent to saying that the fundamental 2-form $\Omega$ is parallel with respect to the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ of $g$. Now,  a measure of the difference of the two types of Ricci forms on $(M, g, J)$ is given as follows:
$\rho^{*}− \rho= \nabla^{*}\nabla \Omega$, hence when $N\neq 0$ (i.e. $J$ is not integrable) it is also  $\nabla\Omega\neq 0$ and we conclude that $\rho$ cannot be closed.

Comment: You've this for symplectic manifolds because they are almost-Kahler manifolds.